# Label text won't change, but view receives variable

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a couple classes that pass around a string through conditionals. In the end, a View Controller catches it and sets it to the text of a label that it owns. Most of it works so far, however, the label text isn't changing. But through NSLog, I can see that the ViewController is seeing the right string.

'.h'

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *theLabel;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *theString;

-(void)setLabelText:(NSString*)someString;
```

`.m`

```
-(void)setLabelText:(NSString*)someString {
    NSLog(@"VC:%@",someString);  //writes out the desired string fine!
    theLabel.text = someString; //doesn't display the text        
}
```

I know that the label works properly because I can call the "setLabelText:" method from `viewDidLoad`, and enter some random string, and it will show up. However, I can't seem to change it from this method. Any help would be appreciated.

"sender"

```
    -(void)sendToMain:(NSString*)string{


    ViewController *newController = [ViewController alloc];
    [newController setLabelText:string];

}
```

Comment: Where's `ip` defined?

Comment: @Undo sorry, fixed the code.

Comment: Try putting this at the end of the code: `NSLog(@"%@", theLabel);`, and see what that gives you.

Comment: @Undo interesting, that line does not get executed at all. So that means that the label text is never being set.

Comment: How are you calling setLabelText?

Comment: From another function that creates the text. I will update my answer in a second

Comment: Made some small changes, and now the log gets executed after the self.theLabel.tex=someString.

Comment: The string that it was supposed to say

Comment: Is your variable label pointing to your interface label?

Comment: did you init your label and viewController before calling your method
eg. theLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the fact that you are creating a new ViewController object, and trying to change a variable on an existing object. If you would like to access your ViewController from a different file, set up the ViewController as a delegate to your other class. Then call the delegate function to set the label's text.

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm) is a tutorial on how to use delegates.

Also, note that only the main thread can make changes to the User Interface. So if you are unsure if the thread executing the conditionals is the main thread, you can add the following code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

//your code block here

});
```

I hope this helps.